# MonoDevelop in Linux -- Terminal Commands

Tags: c#, command-line, mono, terminal, monodevelop

I want to make a C# app in Mono as it's the only programming language I'm mostly comfortable with.

Anyway, ATI Drivers on Linux do not have a Fan control feature and therefore the cards to tend to heat up. For me I prefer to have a cooler card.

What I want to do is run a command such as:

```
aticonfig --pplib-cmd 'set fanspeed 0 70'
```

In a application but I the thing is..How can I run that code so it works, I am currently running Ubuntu 10.04, and it does work in the terminal, but I want to implement it into an application.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not having used Mono, I might be wrong, but I assume you could use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`

Possibly something like this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("aticonfig", "--pplib-cmd 'set fanspeed 0 70'");
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :D Thanks a lot, I've been stressing my head at this.

Comment: You should continue thinking as you were on Windows, as the Novell guys do a fantastic job to make you comfortable:)